# How do I pin the LiveCard using GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm using the GDK and can't find in the documentation how to pin the LiveCard to the timeline. Can somebody help pls? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the examples given in the GDK, the LiveCard.publish() method places the card to the left of the ok glass prompt. Is that what you mean? Isn't that the same as pinning? (making the card appear to the left of the clock).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but the impression I got was that the card may not stay there if the user comes back at a later time, unless I specifically pinned it.

Comment: LiveCards published to the left of the clock will remain there as long as the service that publishes it is running and it does not explicitly unpublish it.